# removing empty array objects from an array in javascript and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to remove empty array object from my array. I have tried filter method but wont work as my array is complex one.

```
const input = 
[
  { daysIn: 1, daysOut: 1, category: "Day Shift" },
  { daysIn: 1, daysOut: 1, category: "Day Shift" },
  { daysIn: null, daysOut: null, category: null }
];
```

Comment: What defines an "empty array object"? It's not obvious from your sample data. What is your expected output?

Comment: my bad  just updated the question

Comment: What have you tried so far? What the expected result do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to include any object which has any non-null value:

```js
const data = [{ daysIn: 1, daysOut: 1, category: "Day Shift" },{ daysIn: 1, daysOut: 1, category: "Day Shift" },{ daysIn: null, daysOut: null, category: null }];

const result = data.filter(o => Object.values(o).some(v => v !== null));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't know we should use `every` or `some`. LOL

Comment: @Phong Using `some` removes the need to negate the result, so it makes it easier to read IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can check length of object to determine it's empty or not.

Update solution:

```js
const data = [
  { daysIn: 1, daysOut: 1, category: "Day Shift" },
  { daysIn: 1, daysOut: 1, category: "Day Shift" }, 
  { daysIn: null, daysOut: null, category: null }];
  
const filterEmptyObject = data => data.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).every(o => {
  if(!o) { 
    // this will also check for undefined, empty string, 0, false, NaN.
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}));

const filteredData = filterEmptyObject(data);

console.log(filteredData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter` and `every`

Approach here is ot reject every objects that have the all falsy values

`x == null` will return true for x of `null/undefined`

```js
const data = [
  { daysIn: 1, daysOut: 1, category: "Day Shift" },
  { daysIn: 1, daysOut: 1, category: "Day Shift" },
  { daysIn: null, daysOut: null, category: null },
  {}
];

const res = data.filter((d) => !Object.values(d).every((v) => v == null));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `every` or `some` based on your requirement.

- Use `every` when you want to filter value if any object **having all properties is `null`**
- Use `some` when you want to filter value if any object **having any property is `null`**

In your case *"remove empty array object"*, I decided use `every`.

```js
const input = 
[
  { daysIn: 1, daysOut: 1, category: "Day Shift" },
  { daysIn: 2, daysOut: 2, category: "Day Shift" },
  { daysIn: null, daysOut: null, category: null }
];

const ouput = input.filter(r => Object.values(r).every(c => c !== null));
console.log(ouput);
```